# Finding unique indices between arrays returned by numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays returned by the function `numpy.where`, like so:

```
A = numpy.where(img == 255)
B = numpy.where(img2 != 0)
```

I need to find number of unique coordinates in `A` and `B`. I initially contemplated using `numpy.intersect1d` to get the number of common indices, and subtract this from the total number of elements from both arrays. But these arrays are not 1-dimensional, so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Any suggestions how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "unique coordinates in A and B". Do you want to know how many coordinates are in both A and B? Exclusively in A or B? Something else?

Comment: I want to know how many total unique coordinates there are across both arrays. So essentially the coordinates in A union B, removing any duplicates.

Comment: Would this work: A_and_B = numpy.where((img == 255) & (img2 !=0))
Or do you need to use A and B?

Comment: With them being of same shapes : `((img == 255) & (img2 != 0)).sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy interprets the xor operator (`^`) as a logical xor, obeying:

```
X|Y|X^Y
0|0| 0
0|1| 1
1|0| 1
1|1| 0
```

---

So you can xor the boolean arrays:

```
(img == 255) ^ (img2 != 0)
```

---

An example:

```
>>> img == 255
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
>>> img != 0
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
>>> (img == 255) ^ (img2 != 0)
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True]])
>>> ((img == 255) ^ (img2 != 0)).sum()
5
```

So there are `5` `True`s in `img` or `img2` that aren't in the other array at the same index.

---

**update:**

If you want the number of `True`s in `img` or `img2` (i.e. the same as the union of two sets of their `True` coordinates). Then use the logical or instead: `|`.

Comment: In the comments to the question it is now stated that the number requested is that of the union of coordinates in A and B, so I think they want OR rather than XOR.

Comment: @jolindbe I think the comment is misleading, "A union B, **removing any duplicates**" so an xor. I will update with the and aswell though just in case.

Comment: I interpreted the "removing any duplicates" as "don't count them twice if in both", but I see your interpretation might be correct as well...

Comment: Thank you so much. The or operator was the one I was looking for (clearly I need to work on explaining what I'm after a little more clearly to avoid confusion!). Thanks for the super detailed answer. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @J.Forrester No problem